# How inspect the css classes of angular material library (without navigator)?

Tags: angular-material

I am currently trying to create my personal components using as base Angular Material Components. I want to change the CSS properties of classes, however It's a convoluted task if I can't see directly the CSS files. There is a way to download the code of this library like a project and inspect the code ?

Answer (score 0):

The angular material repository is available [here](https://github.com/angular/components).

You may also want to refer to the official guides regarding theming and building custom components [here](https://material.angular.io/guides).